# Upload video to Facebook, with RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, api, video, restfb

I'm trying to upload video with RestFB, I tried do this for 2 days, but still can't do it, can somebody help me with this?
What I've done.

I know that I can upload video with this method [video.upload](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/video.upload/), and I must send request to the Facebook video server, so I create class `VideoLegacyFacebookClient`, and put there this server, also I tried make new execute method, which take a `InputStream binaryAttachement` for video, and try to make this code:

```
InputStream is=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/hagen/testing.avi")));
postId = facebookClient.execute("video.upload", null, String.class,is,
                    Parameter.with("title", "My Test Video"),
                    Parameter.with("description", "This is description"));
```

What did I do wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: Is this an attempt to post a video to your wall?

Answer (score 0):

RestFB 1.6.5 may fix this problem; http://restfb.googlecode.com/svn/tags/restfb-project-1.6.5/CHANGELOG says:

> Added support for the new video upload API endpoint via
>   https://graph-video.facebook.com and fixed a multipart filename bug
>   that broke video uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook How-tos about video upload may be useful https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

Answer (score 0):

Below Snippet will work with valid app access token, app secret,

Note: kept videos under resources/videos folder.

Uploading to a Page:

```
DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, appSecret, Version.LATEST);
facebookClient.publish(fbPageID + "/videos", GraphResponse.class, BinaryAttachment.with("videoName.mp4", IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/video/videoName.mp4"))),
                    Parameter.with("description", " Video Description "));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataInputStream is =new DataInputStream(
new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\samiii\\Desktop\\rock.mp4")));
                fbClient.publish("me/videos", FacebookType.class,
                BinaryAttachment.with("rock.mp4", is),
                Parameter.with("title", "rock"),
                Parameter.with("description", "my first vid"));
```

Try this one, it work 100%

Comment: I might work but you should at least take the file paths from the question to the answer and preferably tell how the answer fixes the problem.